# How to check strings for certain requirements

Tags: python

How do I check a string to see if it has uppercase and lowercase, and symbols? I haven't been able to find a answer I understand on the web yet and any help will be really appreciated.

Code:

```
def final_output():
    print("worthless")

def re_main():
    main()

def password_checker(password):
    strength = 0
    letters = isalpha()
    numbers = isdigit()

    if letters and numbers == 'False':
        print("works")


def main():
    password = (input("Please input password:"))
    passwordChecker = (input("Please re-enter your password:"))

    if password != passwordChecker:
        print("Passwords did not match, please try again.")
        re_main()
    else:
        password_checker(password)


main()
```

Comment: What is the problem wtih doing it yourself?

Comment: Because the point of doing this is so I can learn how to check strings for certain requirements, not so I can waste manhours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check each element of the password string for .isupper(), is_lower() and isdigit()

```
passwd = "Password123"
is_upper = any(i.isupper() for i in passwd)
is_lower = any(i.islower() for i in passwd)
is_digit = any(i.isdigit() for i in passwd)
```

Here "any" means that atleast 1 of the character meets the condition(Upper, lower and digit in this case)

Comment: How does it know to check the passwd variable?

Comment: It didn’t – fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several strings from the `string` module (part of the standard Python library) that could be of use here:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
```

You can then check whether any of the characters in your password are in these strings as follows (I have also included a length check):

```
def check_pass(pwd, min_length=8, lower=True, upper=True, punc=True, num=True):
    if len(pwd) < min_length:
        return False
    if lower and not any(char in string.ascii_lowercase for char in pwd):
        return False
    if upper and not any(char in string.ascii_uppercase for char in pwd):
        return False
    if punc and not any(char in string.punctuation for char in pwd):
        return False
    if num and not any(char in string.digits for char in pwd):
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work just fine...

**Code:**

```
import string
s = 'Password#123'

if any(i for i in s if i in string.ascii_uppercase) \
and any(i for i in s if i in string.ascii_lowercase) \
and any(i for i in s if i in string.punctuation): print 'yes'
```

**Output:**

```
yes
```

Hope this helps .. :)